# SWIG: C++ array variable to python list

Tags: python, c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, swig

I'm trying to wrap c++ code with SWIG3.0.
I have a class inside a namespace with a 2d array. I need to access the values.
I have something like this:

```
//example.cpp

namespace n {
    class c {
        double x[2][2] = {
                          {1, 2},
                          {3, 4}
                         };
    };
};
```

I tried this in my swig interface file:

```
//interface.i
...
%typemap(out) double n::c::x[2][2] {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < $dim0; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < $dim1; j++) {
            $result[i][j] = *($1+$dim1*i+j);
        }
}
...
```

When i try to access the values i get the following error:

```
<Swig Object of type 'double (*)[2]' at 0x7f4295431fc0>
>>> x[0][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not subscriptable
```

What am i missing?